# Reload or Rerender Datatable of Jquery in salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, salesforce

I having a problem for Reload or Rerender DataTable using Jquery , I have tried

```
j$('#example1').dataTable()._fnAjaxUpdate();
```

[My Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95137/reload-or-rerender-jquery-datatable-on-radiobutton)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're expecting to double the answers by asking in 2 separate sites, but in any case, you should place the relevant code to answer your question in here as well. Btw, have you managed to fix your JSON (as suggested in the [other question's answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95139))?

Comment: `_fnAjaxUpdate()` is internal function, don't use it. There is [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) that you can use, for example `j$('#example1').DataTable().draw();` but they way you use it after initialization, it's not needed. Please explain what you mean by reload or rerender and why you want it?